# Could not find property "VERSION NAME" on root project?

Tags: android, git, github, gradle

I've forked a project on GitHub. I've then cloned it using Android Studio. But when I try to open it, it says "Could not find property "VERSION NAME" on root project". I presume this has something to do with the grade settings?
    buildscript {

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'
    classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-plugin:1.2'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
```

}

```
def isReleaseBuild() {
return version.contains("SNAPSHOT") == false
```

}

```
allprojects {
version = VERSION_NAME
group = GROUP

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

}

Comment: defaultConfig {
       
        versionName "0.1.0"
    }

Comment: please post build.gradle

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in your build.gradle(app) file.

defaultConfig {
        ...
        versionName "1.0"
    }

Comment: After cloning it from github and trying to open it...all that I have is the gradle files. No source code, no manifest no res folder etc...

Comment: @user2387962 Are you sure the project was successfully cloned?

Comment: ok, it clones correctly. The problem seems to be the "VERSION_NAME" value as shown in the grade.build above.

Comment: @user2387962: declare VERSION_NAME=1.0 (or your version name) in gradle.properties file.